# OSX 10.9 and command line tools, PIL

Tags: python, django, xcode, macos, python-imaging-library

Recently i updated to OSX 10.9 DP.
And PIL stop working properly. Django debug said that "decoder jpeg don't working".
Using stackoverflow answer, i tried to reinstall PIL, but PIL said:
**"fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found" when installing.**

And again i used stackoverflow to find why this happening, and it said that command line tools are not installed, but Xcode 5.0 does not give it download and xcode-select --install give that
**'Can not install software because it is not available from the Software Update center'.**

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I've just install python by homebrew (not linked) and copy all files from /include to my /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
And all started work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `PIL` needs a `C` compiler to install properly, and they're surprisingly hard to come by on OS X. I'd suggest using [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1) instead, which is a more user-friendly fork of PIL that's easier to install. It works nicely with Django too.

Comment: Pillow get same error "fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found" when installing"

Comment: This may seem an odd question, but do you definitely still have a working Python interpreter?

Comment: Yep, python working normal. And other django projects without pil working normal.

Comment: It looks to me like Pillow must also need a C compiler then, which I still think is the best bet for the cause here. I'm afraid I only use a Mac at work and I'm not there again until next week so don't think I can be much help.